# CSS: Fixed with horizontal menu, with variable width tabs, using ul

Tags: css, menu

I have a horizontal menu. The markup looks like this:

```
<ul class="menu">
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Longer Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Submenus and suckerfish dropdowns will come later.

The *ul* needs to span the width of the page (e.g. 100% or 1000px).

The *lis* should vary in width based on their content.

So the result would look like this:

```
-----------------100% of page------------
|--Item 1--|--Longer item 2--|--Item 3--|
```

Now it is easy to do this by fixing a width for each li tag, but because the menu will be CMS driven I need to allow the width of the tabs to vary automatically. With a *table* this would be trivial, but I can't think of a way to do it with a *ul*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my jquery solution:

```
var actualWidth = 1000;
var totalLIWidth = 0;

// Calculate total width of list items
var lis = $('ul li');

lis.each(function(){
    totalLIWidth += $(this).width();
});

// Work out how much padding we need
var requiredPadding = Math.round(((actualWidth-totalLIWidth)/lis.length)/2);

// To account for rounding errors, the error is going to be forced into the first tab.
var roundingErrorFix = (requiredPadding*lis.length*2)+totalLIWidth-actualWidth;

// Apply padding to list items
lis.each(function(i) {
    if(i==0) {
        $(this).css('padding-left',requiredPadding-roundingErrorFix+'px')
            .css('padding-right',requiredPadding-roundingErrorFix+'px');
    }
    else {
        $(this).css('padding-left',requiredPadding+'px')
            .css('padding-right',requiredPadding+'px');
    }
});
```

Comment: Good solution, but it only worked for me after dividing 'roundingErrorFix' by 2 before applying it to the first item.

Comment: Great Answer - one thing to be aware of is that the width of the list item does not include the borders so add the borders to the totalLIWidth at line 10 (after the lis.each loop).

Answer (score 31):

Sorry, but *Display:Table-Man* retired 8 years ago (when Edge 12 finally started supporting Flexbox).

The current best solution:

```css
.menu {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  justify-content: space-between; /* if you want the <li>s to be evenly spread
                                     but not expanded, or ... */
}
.menu > li {
  flex-grow: 1; /* ... if you want the <li>s to grow and fill all space */
}
```

For mobile devices, you can add:

```css
.menu {
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* allow items to wrap to a 2nd line, or ... */
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .menu {
    flex-direction: column; /* ... show the items all one under the other */
  }
}
```

Historical answer:

---

This is a case for

*Display:Table-Man*

```
ul {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
li {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Unfortunately, you should abandon the thought of supporting IEs 6 and 7, but else this is the way to go (or switching to HTML tables, which might or might not be so far away from the semantic content of the markup).

Comment: Boldewyn's answer doesn't work in any of my tests - the list items that result are all of the same width.

Comment: Then I suggest you show your tests (and name the browsers you ran them).

Comment: `table-layout: fixed` gives all cells the same width. If you remove that property then you have 100% of the horizontal space used + variable item length (depending on content).

Comment: JHannes is completely right. The `table-layout: fixed` line should be removed. With (very late) apologies to rda3000, who spotted the problem first!

Answer (score 3):

If you're happy using JavaScript, jQuery could solve the issue as follows

```
var $menu, totalwidth;

$menu = $('ul.menu');
totalwidth = ($menu.width()/100);

$('ul.menu li').each(function(){
    this.css('width',String(Math.floor(this.width()/totalwidth))+'%');
});

$menu.css('width','100%');
```

That's untested, but looks right to me. Comment if you've any questions at all.

Comment: The explicit string cast is unnecessary, but otherwise, you beat me to it ;)

Comment: This will probably end up being trickier than this: $menu.width() will be 100% ( though the actual value you get will be in pixels) by default unless you float the UL because UL is a block element. So you will have to float then unfloat the UL in order to get the right value for totalwidth. Or you could get totalwidth by summing the widths of the LI elements first and then going through them again to adjust to new width.

Comment: That was my first thought, but I didn't want to do two loops...
Floating and unfloating sounds like a safe bet though, should I edit my code?

Comment: Thanks - yeah this is a starting point but it also has to be more complex to account for rounding errors. My answer is too ugly to post, sorry!

Comment: This also produces kind of an ugly result - the padding adjust proportionally to the width of the items. Really we want fixed sized paddings - I'll answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I reckon boldewyn's suggestion should work. I would use this approach for modern browsers and then use conditional comments to feed the following to ie6/7, so that the nav looks ok there , though won't span the 100% width.

```
ul {
  width: 100%;
}
li {
  float:left; // or display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to style the ul (such that it stretches across the entire page), your best bet is to wrap it in a div, and style the div, and then allow the ul to just stretch as far as its content carries it