# forcing menus to take up 100% of width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this top bar menu:

http://yoursdproperty.com/

I need to have the text always take up 100% of the width. how do i do this?

if I add more links i want the sizing to be dynamic

any ideas?

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML and CSS in the question body instead of linking.

Comment: you will find some information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859243/css-fixed-with-horizontal-menu-with-variable-width-tabs-using-ul

Comment: Are you saying you want the 6 links "Home, Buying Property, etc" to always take up the full with of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

specify a width as a percentage.

```
<ul>
    <li>something</li>
    <li>something</li>
    <li>something</li>
    <li>something</li>
<ul>

ul li {
    width:25%;
    display:inline;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't handle adding new items however, he wants it to always add up to 100% without having to modify the widths every time he adds a link (or links may be dynamic).

Comment: Good point. I see re-read the questions and understand it better.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your browser requirements: For modern browsers you can do something like:

```
ul {
    display: table;
}
li {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

for older browser compatibility you might have to use a real table.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately the only way I can think to do it without JavaScript is to use Tables.  Yeeich.

Answer (score 1):

you can just not specify the width or set it to auto