# Evenly spaced and justified horizontal list menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu, center

I searched and found no solution to spacing out a series of lis for a list style menu. I realized CSS alone can't do it so I added some javascript (jQuery). I didn't want the same widths for each LI, I wanted even padding with no leftover space. If anyone can take this concept and simplify my awful javascript or offer alternatives please do so. See example here: http://www.valweb.com/menuTest/

Comment: You will probably get more helpful answers if you ask this question on http://doctype.com

Answer (score 1):

As CSS alone can do so but old IEs can't, why not use `display: table; (and table-cell)` as a default (your 2nd example is just great) and use `display: inline; zoom: 1; /* display: inline-block for IE */ padding: 0 Npx;` for IE<8 with the help of conditional comments?
And maybe JS/jQuery if you really must care about IE6/7 users, only served to them.

PS: you should add a rule for **:focus**

```
.mainMenu li a:hover,
.mainMenu li a:focus {
  /* ... */
}
```

as E. Meyer [states in the comments of its reset.css stylesheet](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/index.html): ;-)

```
/* remember to define focus styles! */
:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Felipe. I've gotten so used to throwing reset on everything I hadn't actually read his comments in a while. I included css tables as an example that I wasn't happy with. However, I found my same issue solved here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859243/css-fixed-with-horizontal-menu-with-variable-width-tabs-using-ul almost a year ago. Quite similar to mine.